# Format CSV Export From radGrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid, telerik-grid

I am trying to format my CSV export from a radGrid. It exports fine but it doesn't seem to pick up any of the styles. This what I am using:

```
protected void imgBtnExportCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    foreach (GridDataItem item in grdLeadList.MasterTableView.Items) //loop through each grid item
      {
        if (item.Selected)
          {
            selectedItems.Add(item.ItemIndex);
          }
      }

foreach (GridDataItem item in grdLeadList.MasterTableView.Items)
  {
    // for particuler item
    item["CompanyName"].Font.Name = "Calibri";
    item["CompanyName"].Style["font-size"] = "8pt";
    item["CompanyName"].Style["background-color"] = "#FFF";
    item["CompanyName"].Style["vertical-align"] = "middle";
  }
  grdLeadList.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
  grdLeadList.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
                grdLeadList.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueName("ClientSelectColumn").Visible = false;
            grdLeadList.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueName("EditCommandColumn1").Visible = false;
            grdLeadList.ExportSettings.FileName = "ColderLeads";
            grdLeadList.MasterTableView.ExportToCSV();

  }
```

Is it possible to format CSV export from radGrid?

Thanks!

Comment: CSV is just that, comma separated values - no formatting.  Have you tried exporting to excel instead (http://goo.gl/xYMEM)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is just a text file, nothing special about it - Excel just happens to open it by default. What you what is to export your grid to Excel.